# Google Search Console URL Parameter Tool reports no URLs monitored

Tags: google-search-console, url-parameters

Why doesn't Google Search Console monitor any parameters on my pages?

[image]

I tried to change the URL parameters on November 2019, but Google still hasn't recognized the changes.

Comment: I assume that you actually do use those parameters on your site, correct?   Have you checked your logs to see if Googlebot is avoiding the ones you've asked it not to crawl?

Comment: Yes, we are using this parameters on site. And there is nothing in logs too :<

Comment: So at least Googlebot isn't crawling URLs with them.

Comment: So it's like offers list - the most important part of the page :D Maybe you have any idea why it may be like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug/glitch on Google's end. Many sites have had this same issue (https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/16282442). Google has also indicated that they may be deprecating the tool entirely soon, so this may be a sign that there is very little resources being dedicated to it.